# Python list inter-element operation - can this be done with list comprehension?

Tags: python, list

I'm doing some return calculations and I'd like to do the below as elegantly as possible, but my knowledge of list comprehension is not good enough. (The list x can be any length, not just 4 elements, the elements are floating point numbers).

```
x = [a, b, c, d]
y = [(a-b)/b, (b-c)/c, (c-d)/d]
```

Thanks!

Comment: do you have a test-case?

Comment: @RudolfMühlbauer I tried a for loop and got it to work, but it felt 'wrong'

Comment: Programming in a way you understand is never wrong - it is quite likely that your code will be read by someone with a comparable knowledge of python. While the language offers a lot of shortcuts, I often prefer the 'more intuitive' (direct) version - to make it easy for colleagues!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems plausible, doesn't it?

```
>>> x = [1.,2.,3.,4.]
>>> [ ((e-f)/f) for e,f in zip ( x[:-1], x[1:]) ]
[-0.5, -0.3333333333333333, -0.25]
```

Comment: @DSM lol; even the same example! you wouldn't have to delete it, though - you had some good explanation!

Answer (score 3):

List comprehension is not always the best way to go and is just a syntactic shortcut which is aimed at having shorter cleaner code.
For complicated operation like yours, I would recommend going the old way. 
As a rule of thumb, I always think that if you have hard time writing it, others will certainly have hard time reading it.

Anyway, here are the two possible way of doing this:

**The pythonic way using list comprehension:**

```
y = [(x[i] - x[i + 1]) / x[i + 1] for i in xrange(len(x - 1))]
```

**The old fashioned way:**

```
y = []
for i in range(len(x - 1)):
    a = x[i]
    b = x[i + 1]
    y.append((a - b) / b)
```

Comment: Ah! beat me by 16 seconds. +1, still

Answer (score 1):

You could use `zip` as others have suggested, or

```
[(x[i]-x[i+1])/x[i+1] for i in range(len(x)-1)]
```

Comment: it should be xrange(len(x) - 1) => 0 .. x-2 I think

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
y = [(x[i-1]-x[i])/x[i] for i in range(1,len(x))]
```

Hope this helps!